# Any text-editor which list numbers of words in a file?

Tags: debian, editors

Does anybody of a GUI FOSS text-editor which shows number of words by default in a document. If not the one in which having such a preference is the easiest. I am looking for a text-editor which counts words in real-time if possible.

Comment: In vim, `g<Ctrl-G>` gets you a word count.

Comment: And in emacs it's `M-=` for the current region (so `C-x h M-=` for the whole file). I would think most text editors have this feature, is there some other requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`geany` will do this

`Tools->Wordcount` provides Line, Word & Character counts in a pop up diaglogue.

Comment: close but no dice, need something which does it in real-time and *is not* emacs or vim but proper GUI. If it's an add-on functionality that's ok/bearable.

Comment: Shame such basic stats are buried somewhere in the menu instead of being displayed in the status bar.

Answer (score 2):

The Gnome Text Editor (gedit) provides this through its menu under: `Tools > Document Statistics`. The popup window that appears can be left open as you work, and you can click its update icon whenever you want a fresh result.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for something like `Atom` (https://atom.io/), which has a `wordcount` package (https://atom.io/packages/wordcount) that adds word and character counts to the status bar.  Their web site has source and `.deb` downloads.  `Atom` is MIT licensed.

To add the `wordcount` package to `Atom`, choose `Edit` Menu -> `Preferences` -> `Install`, select `Packages`, and search for `wordcount`.  Click on its `Install` button, and as soon it's installed your word/character counts will show at the bottom right of each edit buffer.

Comment: sadly, for reasons unknown, the package is not there in Debian package archive, although there are quite a few packages in Debian which are MIT licensed :(

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=atom&searchon=names&suite=sid&section=all