# text-editor which counts words not characters?

Tags: text-processing, editors, text

Is there a text-editor which counts words not characters in GNU/Linux ? I tried out various editors but couldn't figure out which one has it but none of the popular ones seem to have it. Looking for advice. No vi or emacs but one that regular people use, like leafpad or Gedit/pluma like that.

Comment: *vi like emacs* does this too (the `count-words` command).  probably vim does it.

Comment: I did narrow it down, hopefully this is now answerable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237422/any-text-editor-which-list-numbers-of-words-in-a-file which seems to have a valid (yet unaccepted) answer.

Comment: Glad to be one of the irregular people in this world, never even having heard of leafpad or pluma.

Answer (score 2):

## Emacs

There are at least two different minor modes in emacs that display word-count information in the mode line, as well as a built-in command.

Without installing anything extra, you can use <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd> at any time to see the word count of the current buffer or selection.  For older versions, you can use <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>|</kbd> wc

Alternatively, you can install and use one of the minor modes that offers this functionality in the mode line: either [word-count-mode](http://taiyaki.org/elisp/word-count/src/word-count.el) or [wc-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/wcMode).

([Source](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WordCount))

Answer (score 2):

## Vim

You could call `wc` in the `:!wc -w %`

or try

the following : `ggVGgCtrl+g`

The output will be
Selected 26 of 26 Lines; 40 of 40 Words; 1352 of 1352 Bytes

Comment: Or just `g Ctrl-g` (cf. `:h g_CTRL-G`).